# Does postgresql support lookbehind regexp?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

If yes, pls provide an example for lookbehind or an alternative.

I'm trying to extract the sequence name without '

```
select table_name,
       column_name,
       regexp_replace(substring(column_default from '''.*(?='')'),'''','','g') as sequence
FROM information_schema.columns
```

Answer (score 11):

As of 9.6, it does accept positive lookbehinds using `(?<=re)`, documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINTS-TABLE).

Comment: To clarify, it also accepts negative lookbehinds using `(?<!re)`. For example `select 'ABC' ~ '(?<!A)BC';` returns `f`.

Answer (score 8):

It didn't support it at the sql level last I checked, but you can use plperl to work around the limitation if absolutely necessary. (Heavy regexing generally doesn't belong at the DB level, though...)

In your particular example, consider using a negative class instead: `[^']` (escape it as needed), or a [non-greedy wildcard: `.*?`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-QUANTIFIERS-TABLE).

Adding to this re your specific question, unless you actually create your sequence manually its name will always be:

```
tablename_colname_seq
```

Also FWIW, the following two defaults have a different behavior if you use multiple schemas and search paths in your app:

```
nextval('foo'::regclass)  -- find foo once
nextval('foo'::text)      -- find foo each time
```

Comment: Sometimes lookbehind can be replaced with an alternation with capturing group on one side, as explained here: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html