# How to "not include" some piece in regex pattern

Tags: regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Given string  `12,.34.56`

I need split this string by point (`.`), but only by these points, which previous character is not comma (`,`)

That is, from string above, must be retrieve result

```
12,.34
56
```

I am trying this:

`SELECT regexp_split_to_table('12,.34.56', E'[^,]\\\.')`

this returns:

```
    12,.3
    56
```

As we see, symbol `4` is removed, reason understood: `[^,]` means "some symbol" except comma, and in this case, "some symbol" was turned `4`

Question: how to prevent this? how to *not include* this piece: `[^,]` in pattern?

Comment: This would be the regular expression: `/(?<!,)\./`. However, I'm not sure if this is supported by PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is not supported by Postgres regular expressions, the workaround is to replace `,.` with another (unique) combination of characters and later convert it back:

```
SELECT replace(unnest(string_to_array(
               replace('12,.34.56.78,.34', ',.','~^~'), '.')), '~^~', ',.')
```

I am also using [`unnest(sting_to_array())`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) instead of [`regexp_split_to_table()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) because it has shown to scale better.

Answer (score 2):

This is called a *negative lookbehind assertion*. Unfortunately [PostgreSQL doesn't support these in its regular expression implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6923249/398670).

You can work around that by using more complex queries ... as Erwin just posted I was writing this.

While PostgreSQL's native regexp implementation doesn't support this, *pl/perl does*, so you can use PL/Perl to perform more complex regular expression tasks when you can't find simpler and more efficient workarounds that use PostgreSQL's built-ins.